# Can anything useful be said about or done with an obvious generalisation of the Mobius function?

Tags: number-theory, mobius-function

For a natural number $n$, the standard Mobius function $\mu(n)$ is defined to be zero if the square of any prime divides $n$, and otherwise either $-1$ or $1$ according as n has respectively an odd or even number of prime factors.

Values for the squarefree cases can be expressed formally as a product of $-1$ over every prime $p$ dividing $n$. So there is a pretty obvious and natural generalisation to similar multiplicative function defined as follows for any given integer $k > 1$, in which $\xi$ denotes a primitive root of $x^k = 1$ and $ind_{n}(p)$ the maximum power of $p$ dividing $n$ :

$\mu_k(n) = 0$ if any $p^k | n$, or $\prod_{p|n}\xi^{ind_{n}(p)}$ otherwise

I wondered if functions like this would have any neat or useful properties. I couldn't see them mentioned in the Wikipedia article on the Mobius function, so perhaps not.

Comment: The Möbius function is an extremely natural and useful function for many different reasons (the Möbius inversion formula chief among them). Varying it in an ad hoc manner is very unlikely to produce a useful function.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is ad hoc exactly. As I mentioned (after an edit!), it seems a fairly natural extension.

Comment: [Generalizations in use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Generalizations).

Comment: I am under the impression that it is more natural to think of $\mu$ as a book-keeping device for the purposes of inclusion-exculsion. It may be possible to have uses for extensions of the type you ask about, but I foresee mightmares related to the freedoms of choices in choosing various primitive roots of unity for $\zeta$ for various $k$. $-1$ is unambiguous :-)

Comment: I would say (without trying to cause offense) that it is only natural if one looks at the Möbius function superficially, rather than structurally.